# How can my syntax error be fixed?

Tags: java, syntax

I am a beginner with weak understanding of java. Please could you help me correct the error saying:

```
         // [line 45] Syntax error on token " (", ; expected
```

On the line:

```
      private static int countWords(String str) {
```

This error appears twice on this line. I've tried experimenting with adding and deleting brackets and I've tried adding ';' to my code but it only makes the code display more errors. Underneath there is my code to help identify the error better:

```
import java.util.*;

 public class HDtest9 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) { // have created infinite loop
        System.out.print("Enter text: ");
        String sentence = in.nextLine();
          System.out.println("You have entered: " + sentence); // to Print string
        System.out.println("The total number of characters is " + sentence.length()); // to print Entered string's length
        System.out.println("This piece of text has " + countWords(sentence) + " words.");

        if (sentence.equals("quit")) { // if enterd value is "quit" than it comes out of loop
            break;
        } else {

            String[] words = sentence.split(" "); // get the individual words

 int maxWordLength = 0;
 int wordLength = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

     wordLength = array[i].length();
     if (wordLength > maxWordLength) {
         maxWordLength = wordLength; 
   }
    int[] intArray = new int[maxWordLength + 1];
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
 intArray[array[i].length()]++;
 for (int i = 1; i < intArray.length; i++) {
 out.printf("%d word(s) of length %d<br>", intArray[i], i);
   }
       }
            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
                System.out.println( "word " + i + ": " + words[i] + " = " + words[i].length() + " characters");


        }


    }
    in.close();
}

private static int countWords(String str) {
    String words[] = str.split(" ");
    int count = words.length;
    return count;
}
   }
  }
```

Thank you very much for any help, it's much appreciated!

Comment: At least one issue, is you use `array` but have an array variable `words`.

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Comment: You will want to really work on your code indentation as your current random indents make your code very hard to read and thus very hard to understand. Good indentations also make it easier for **you** to find the type of bug that you're trying to fix in this question. In the future (and even now), you will want to use an indentation style that is uniform and consistent. I usually avoid using tabs for indenting (forum software often doesn't play well with tabs) and indent each code block 4 spaces.

Comment: You should know that these questions are almost exclusively offtopic. See the close reason when a few more votes have been cast.

Comment: I really apologize, I just wanted some help. Thank you everyone for your answers, I'm trying to apply them to my code now.

Comment: No problem. Asking questions here is a learned skill and will get better with time, but I really want to stress that your indentations are killing you more than us. It is because of your poor indents that you didn't readily see your error. With effort, this will all improve. Much luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected and working code

```
import java.util.*;

public class HDtest9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) { // have created infinite loop
            System.out.print("Enter text: ");
            String sentence = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("You have entered: " + sentence); // to Print string
            System.out.println("The total number of characters is " + sentence.length()); // to print Entered string's length
            System.out.println("This piece of text has " + countWords(sentence) + " words.");

            if (sentence.equals("quit")) { // if enterd value is "quit" than it comes out of loop
                break;
            } else {

                String[] words = sentence.split(" "); // get the individual words

                int maxWordLength = 0;
                int wordLength = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

                    wordLength = words[i].length();
                    if (wordLength > maxWordLength) {
                        maxWordLength = wordLength;
                    }
                }
                int[] intArray = new int[maxWordLength + 1];
                for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    intArray[words[i].length()]++;
                }
                for (int i = 1; i < intArray.length; i++) {
                    System.out.printf("%d word(s) of length %d<br>", intArray[i], i);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("word " + i + ": " + words[i] + " = " + words[i].length() + " characters");
                }

            }

        }
        in.close();
    }

    private static int countWords(String str) {
        String words[] = str.split(" ");
        int count = words.length;
        return count;
    }

}
```

Comment: And instead of <br> you can use \n

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to declare your `countWords()` method inside your `main()` method, which isn't legal in Java, so the compiler is choking trying to parse your method signature.

If you move it outside where it belongs, you will only have the other 8 or so undeclared and duplicate variable errors left to deal with.

Please use proper indentation and naming in your code.  It will help you (and others) read it, and prevent this sort of mistake.

Answer (score 2):

On the line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
```

You have no opening curly brace

Change to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
```

Also, **please fix your indentation**, it is very hard to read and see if there are any more bugs.

Comment: Yes, this was the main cause of the error, thank you!